# Adding to stringbuffer comma

Tags: java, android

I need to add comma to stringbuffer.I added comma through path + "," but in last left excess comma. I use library **MultipleImageSelect**
My code :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0, l = images.size(); i < l; i++) {
            stringBuffer.append(images.get(i).path + "\n");
        }
        textView.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check whether you're at the last iteration. In that case you don't add the comma.

```
for (int i = 0, l = images.size(); i < l; i++) {
    stringBuffer.append(images.get(i).path + (i < l-1 ? "," : "") + "\n");
}
```

If you don't mind making it a bit longer, you can spare some cycles by avoiding the useless addition of an empty string like this

```
for (int i = 0, l = images.size(); i < l; i++) {
    stringBuffer.append(images.get(i).path)
    if (i < l-1) {
        stringBuffer.append(",");
    }
    stringBuffer.append("\n");
}
```

Comment: Elegant but probably more efficient and not ugly with a conditional statement as you spare n-1 concatenation

Comment: @davidxxx Hi bro. Can you explain If I chose 10 files and I need to print just one file

Comment: @davidxxx amended as per your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add the String into a List and then join them with `,`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
        List<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0, l = images.size(); i < l; i++) {
            buffer.add(images.get(i).path);
        }
        textView.setText(String.join(",\n", buffer));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you . Can you explain If I chose 10 files and I need to print just one file

Comment: Is `map` supported on android's sdk? Because at that point you could also remove the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove last `character` from `StringBuffer`.

```
    for (int i = 0, l = images.size(); i < l; i++) {
        stringBuffer.append(images.get(i).path + "\n");

    }
    if(!stringBuffer.isEmpty()) {
        stringBuffer.substring(0,stringBuffer.length()-1);
    }
```